# Using super() in classes

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to use super() for a simple class hierarchy in this manner:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class FullTime(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, satOff, freeDays=[], alDays=[], programDays=[]):
        global satsOffDict
        global dayDict
        super(Employee, self).__init__(name)
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I've read that you need to make the parent object type object (new style classes) in order for super to work. If I change class Employee(object) to class Employee(), I get this error:

```
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

What's going on?

Comment: You might want to be careful passing lists as the defaults the `__init__` like that.  That's just begging for interesting behavior ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the *current* class in `super()`:

```
super(FullTime, self).__init__(name)
```

`super()` looks for requested methods relative to the first argument; you started the search from `Employee` instead, looking for the parent classes; `object.__init__()` is the next parent method that matches in that case.

You need to use the current class, because Python needs to search the base classes in [Method Resolution Order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/); that ordering depends on how your current class is derived from it's base classes (especially if there is multiple inheritence or a base class ends up being referenced multiple times).

On Python 3.x, you can use `super()` without any arguments, and the [compiler will add an extra hint to your method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) so that it can determine the correct class to start from.

Comment: Could you comment on why this is?  I've always wondered.  It seems as though the derived class should be trivially easy to identify automatically by the interpreter.  Is there a use case for using something different as the first parameter?

Comment: Note that in 3.x, `super()` can take no arguments and work fine.

Comment: @acjohnson55: The MRO of the base classes depend on the inheriting class. Imagine a class that inherits from *two* super classes.

Comment: So, you're saying that you can use a base class in ``super``, but then a compatible method better be in *the base class's* superclass lineage someplace?

Comment: @acjohnson55: Exactly. And it might be the wrong one, if there was a different MRO path to follow based on your current class.

Comment: Okay, cool.  Man, it really seems as though it would have made so much more sense to just make the first argument optional.  I would go out on a limb and say the overwhelming majority of invocations of ``super`` are for situations where normal MRO is perfectly fine.

Comment: @acjohnson55: Explicit is better than implicit though. But sometimes practicality beats purity, so the no-args `super()` option was added in Python 3.

Comment: I mean, if we like explicit so much, why not go back to static typing and C++ style generics? Or we can always just write in assembly :) Thanks for the info, though

Answer (score 2):

When you use `super` in Python, you should be specifying the *derived* type (that is, the class in which you're writing the call) as the first parameter.

```
super(FullTime, self).__init__(name)
```